# using local variables in parallel.foreach

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I'm having a really hard time working this out.

The code is supposed to import images from a file dialog. And each image is supposed to be processed and sent to class correct.
Processor is a class that detects shapes, so basically I am sending every image and detecting shapes in it(filtered to a certain criteria within the class processor)

newList will get the centers of all the shapes in an image.

I have little knowledge in Parallelism and I can't seem to figure how to work this out.
Keep in mind that I do not need to pass anything from one iteration to another. I just want images to be processed and corrected each at a time, with the entire operation divided to threads.

> I have every iteration a stand alone one and I need not return anything from one iteration to another.

Currently the problem is that the results returned from class correct are sometimes incorrect. i guess it is because processor and newList must also be local? If yes how can I solve this? If not where have I gone wrong?

Also keep in mind that using a normal foreach works just fine

Here is my code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ofd.FileNames,
        (file) =>
        {
            Image exam = Image.FromFile(file);
            var cvImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>((Bitmap)exam);
            processor = processorMain;
            processor.ProcessImage(cvImage);
            List<Point> newList = new List<Point>();
            newList = processor.getList();
            correct.correct(cvImage, answerKey, nOptions);
        });
```

Comment: Did you notice that you didn't actually at all describe what your problem is? :)

Comment: The problem is that this Parallel.Foreach is not functional and I have explained the reason. I have every iteration a stand alone one and I need not return anything from one iteration to another.

Comment: `Parallel.Foreach is not functional` I don't know what that means. `I have explained the reason` you have said what it's *supposed* to do.  You haven't described what behavior you are seeing vs. what you are expecting.

Comment: That `processor = processorMain;` looks very suspicious. But like the other comments already say, there is no clear cut question here.

Comment: Yeah I mean that the problem with this code is that it requires a return of a value in the body. And as I have said, I do not need that for every iteration is stand alone. What I need to know is how is the correct approach to do this? Thank you again

Comment: you are using a very strange overload of `Parallel.Foreach()`, try [keeping it simple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So use one of the [other overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992001(v=vs.110).aspx) that does require you to return anything. This particular overload is designed for when you want to accumulate some state. We need all the details. Is there a compiler error? runtime exception? something else unexpected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual question/problem was stated in a comment:

> I have every iteration a stand alone one and I need not return anything from one iteration to another.

In that case you do not want your `Image`s to be Thread-local, you just need them local. So the solution is to simplify:

```
  Parallel.ForEach(ofd.FileNames,
    (file) =>
    {
        var cvImage = new Image<Bgr, byte>((Bitmap)exam);
        processor = processorMain;
        processor.ProcessImage(cvImage);
        List<Point> newList = new List<Point>();
        newList = processor.getList();
        correct.correct(newList, cvImage, answerKey, nOptions);
    });
```

But your code is not really using `file` anywhere so this is just a rough guess. It cannot be correct yet.

And on the other hand, the usages of `processorMain`, `answerKey` and `nOptions` are potential problems.

---

And after a few more comments, what you need is:

```
IList<Image> result = ofd.FileNames
       .AsParallel()
       .Select( (file) => 
{
    Image exam = Image.FromFile(file);
    ...
    return exam;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply
This is where I am using the file. I am creating an image from every file name and then this image is processed and then sent to the correct class

Comment: But there is no use of `file` anywhere in your code. You're not out of the woods yet.

Comment: As I have said, file is used to create an image from it
So there is a missing line in this code right before the cvImage declaration which is:
Image exam = Image.FromFile(file);
And as you have anticipated, there are still problems because of proeccor and newList. They should be localized as well? If yes, how?

Comment: Edit your question to clear things up. And when you want better answers you will need to describe better what should happen. We can now only see a small part of a solution that is possibly broken.

Comment: I have updated the question and the code, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in these lines of code:

```
        processor = processorMain;
        processor.ProcessImage(cvImage);
        List<Point> newList = processor.getList(); // don't make a new list and then just throw it away by overwriting it.
```

It looks like `processor` is processing your image and storing some results which you later access with the call to `processor.getList()`. But if multiple threads are running in parallel, a second thread might call `ProcessImage` after the first thread has called it but before the first thread gets to `processor.getList()`. This means the first thread will get the list results from the second thread.

The simplest solution would be to create a processor in each iteration:

```
        processor = new MyProcessorType();
        processor.ProcessImage(cvImage);
        List<Point> newList = new List<Point>();
        newList = processor.getList();
```

This is dependent on the assumption that the processor doesn't rely on any static data.

Another option would be to modify the processor so that the point list is stored in thread local storage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand what you mean and that is true.But let me explain to you why I always use processor = processorMain. processorMain contains predefined settings for the image processing, if I write processor = new MyProcessorType(), I would lose these settings. So processor = processorMain is basically resetting the values inside processorMain which I need in every image processing. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you have every thread sharing the same state. The state includes that configuration. The problem is, every thread is calling `ProcessImage` which manipulates the state, then they call `getList` to read that state. You need to copy what configuration you need for each thread and give them their own working space. If they're all working with the same object at the same time you're going to have these issues.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by applying a lock on newList and correct